# how (replace|create) an enum field on rails 2.0 migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I would like to create an enum field at sone migration I'm doing, I tried searching in google but I can't find the way to do it in the migration

the only thing I found was

```
  t.column :status, :enum, :limit => [:accepted, :cancelled, :pending]
```

but looks like the above code runs only on rails 1.xxx and since I'm running rails 2.0

this what I tried but it fails

```
class CreatePayments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :payments do |t|
      t.string :concept
      t.integer :user_id
      t.text :notes
      t.enum :status, :limit => [:accepted, :cancelled, :pending]

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :payments
  end
end
```

So, in case that isn't allowed, what do you think could be a good solution? just a text field, and validating from the model?

Comment: I know it's been a long time since your question was posted and that it was meant for rails 2.0. But I just wanted to register that rails 4.1 has ActiveRecord accepting enums. Documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: thanks!!! I moved to Django anyway :)

Answer (score 37):

You can manually specify the type by using the `t.column` method instead. Rails will interpret this as a string column, and you can simply add a validator to the model like Pavel suggested:

```
class CreatePayments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :payments do |t|
      t.string :concept
      t.integer :user_id
      t.text :notes
      t.column :status, "ENUM('accepted', 'cancelled', 'pending')"

      t.timestamps
    end    
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :payments
  end
end

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_inclusion_of :status, :in => %w(accepted cancelled pending)
end
```

Comment: What about when using `add_column`?

Comment: add_column :tablename, :columnname, "ENUM('xx')"

Comment: Most relevant answer!  Integrates nicely into Rails, without the use of any third party code!

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer; for those on pgsql; add following in `self.up` **before** the `create_table` call: `execute "CREATE TYPE payment_status AS ENUM ('accepted', 'cancelled', 'pending')"` and use that type in column definition as `t.column :status, "payment_status"`. Also, don't forget to add a corresponding `execute "DROP TYPE payment_status"` **after** the drop_table in the `self.down`

Answer (score 24):

Look at tip #3 on http://zargony.com/2008/04/28/five-tips-for-developing-rails-applications

This exactly what you need!

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates_inclusion_of :status, :in => [:active, :inactive]

   def status
     read_attribute(:status).to_sym
   end

   def status= (value)
     write_attribute(:status, value.to_s)
   end
 end
```

HTH

Comment: This, however solves the problem, is just a workaround. And not solution to real problem asked by OP. Answer by Adam Lassek is more relevant.

Answer (score 9):

You can try the (very) comprehensive jeff's [enumerated_attribute gem](http://github.com/jeffp/enumerated_attribute) OR go with this simple workaround:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  SEX = [:male, :female]

  def sex
    SEX[read_attribute(:sex)]
  end

  def sex=(value)
    write_attribute(:sex, SEX.index(value))
  end
end
```

And then declare the `sex` attribute as an integer:

```
t.integer :sex
```

This worked very fine for me! =D

Comment: can you explain a bit how this works? is that changing a constant or ?

Comment: It just maps integer values to symbols. =)

Comment: What happens if you add a new item to the middle of the list? SEX = [:male, :alien, :female] will change all the existing females into aliens, since :alien now has an index of 1.

Answer (score 4):

I have dozens of these little enums, with 3-300 entries in each. I implement them as lookup tables. I don't have a model file for each one; I use some metaprogramming to generate a model for each, since each table has the same set of columns (id, name, description).

Since some of the sets had enough elements to warrant their own table, it was more consistent to move them all to tables. Just another option if you'll have more of these enums later.

**EDIT:** Here's how I generate the models:

```
ACTIVE_RECORD_ENUMS = %w{
  AccountState
  ClientType
  Country
  # ...
}

ACTIVE_RECORD_ENUMS.each do |klass|
  eval "class #{klass} < ActiveRecord::Base; end"
  klass.constantize.class_eval do
    class << self

      def id_for(name)
        ids[name.to_s.strip.humanize.downcase]
      end

      def value_for(id)
        values[id.to_i]
      end

      def values
        @values ||= find(:all).inject({}) {|h,m| h[m.send(primary_key)] = m.name; h}
      end

      def ids
        @ids ||= self.values.inject({}) {|h, {k, v}| h[v.downcase] = k; h}
      end

    end
  end
end
```

This file lives in the models directory, and is included in `application_config.rb`. This lets me do stuff like this:

```
AccountState.ids 
# => {"active" => 1, "deleted" => 2}
AccountState.values 
# => {1 => "Active", 2 => "Deleted"}
AccountState.id_for("Active") 
# => 1
AccountState.value_for(1) 
# => "active"
```

Comment: I'd be very interested to see the code or hear more about the metaprogramming you're doing to accomplish this if it's not too much trouble.

Comment: Edited to add some code. I haven't looked at it in a while and found I had to look up (again) what inject does. Perhaps that's an argument for using collect instead...

Comment: Very nifty idea. I have lots of those lookup tables that I never want to make model files for.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the [enum-column](https://rubyforge.org/projects/enum-column/) plugin on RubyForge?

Answer (score 3):

Similarly, the *enumerated_attribute* gem manages enums at the object level.

```
enum_attr :status, %w(accepted cancelled ^pending)
```

Define a string in the migration

```
t.string :status
```

Also provides some nice features like dynamic predicate methods.

http://github.com/jeffp/enumerated_attribute/tree/master

Answer (score 2):

Add the following:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters #:nodoc:
    class TableDefinition
      def enum(*args)
        options = args.extract_options!
        column_names = args

        column_names.each { |name| column(name, 'enum', options) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

to lib/enum/table_definition.rb and include it in your init.rb.

Comment: nice piece of code, I will try to implement it, question, this looks easy an nice, so why rails doesn't include it in the core?

Comment: Probably because not all databases support ENUMs.

Answer (score 0):

ok, just read the whole rails api and found what I neeed and I dont like :(
Rails doesn't support emum as native type on migrations, [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#M001936) is the info, I need to search for a plugin or other method.

I will keep you posted.

Comment: IIRC, rails only supports features that are implemented by all the supported databases, so there's no "out of the box" enum support.

Comment: FYI, neither Java's Hibernate supports this without extension.

Comment: great! now I just need to know how to run Hibernate on ROR :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option: drop to SQL.

```
def self.up
  execute "ALTER TABLE `payments` ADD `status` ENUM('accepted', 'cancelled', 'pending')"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

With simple_form i use this:

```
<%= f.input :gender, :collection => {'Male' => 'male','Female' => 'female'}, :include_blank => false %>
```