# How do I describe an enumeration column in a Rails 3 migration?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, enums, migration

How do I describe an enumeration column in a Rails 3 migration?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Rails 4.1 [contains enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) for now!

You can write just

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [ :admin, :user, :banned ]
end
```

For migration write

```
t.integer :status
```

**Rails 3 & 4.0**

Best solution in my opinion is [simple_enum](https://github.com/lwe/simple_enum) gem.

Comment: Unfortunately the values are stored as integers not as ENUM with several downsides: http://hn.meteor.com/posts/6925010-32d11

Comment: @migu this is de-facto standard of rails enum. `simple_enum` gem works the same. See updated answer

Comment: @migu Can you double check that link - I'm super interested in it but it no worky for me. :) Thanks.

Comment: They asked about rails 3, not 4

Answer (score 9):

In a Rails 3 Migration you can do the following:

```
class CreateFoo < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :foo do |t|
      t.column :foobar, "ENUM('foo', 'bar')"
    end
  end
end
```

This will create the table with the single column "foobar" and the values.

Answer (score 5):

You can describe an enumeration column with:

```
t.column 'role', 'user_role'
```

I created the enum type with:

```
execute "CREATE TYPE user_role AS ENUM ('consultant', 'admin');"
```

Inspecting the database:

```
    Column     |          Type          | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
---------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 role          | user_role              |           | plain    |              |
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates_inclusion_of :status, :in => [:active, :inactive]

   def status
     read_attribute(:status).to_sym
   end

   def status= (value)
     write_attribute(:status, value.to_s)
   end
 end
```

Comment: It's on model. I need a migration.

Comment: This was pasted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693928/how-replacecreate-an-enum-field-on-rails-2-0-migrations

Comment: This was pasted from http://zargony.com/2008/04/28/five-tips-for-developing-rails-applications

Answer (score 3):

I like **enumerated_attribute** gem: https://github.com/jeffp/enumerated_attribute

Easy enum for your models, objects and views.

Works fine with rails 3.1

Answer (score 3):

This will also work....

`add_column :table_name, :column_name, "enum('abc','def','ghi')", :default => 'abc'`

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the enum_fu gem: https://github.com/ikspres/enum_fu

Comment: Has not been updated since 2009. Does not seem to be actively maintained.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was mapping it from symbols to integers

```
TYPE_MAP = { type_one: 1, type_two:2, another_type:3 }

def type
    TYPE_MAP.key(read_attribute(:type))
end

def type=(s)
    write_attribute(:type, TYPE_MAP[s])
end
```

But for the controller you have to map it again like this:

```
 def create
  @cupon_type = CuponType.new(params[:cupon_type])
  @cupon_type.type = params[:cupon_type][:type].to_sym
```

Note the **.to_sym** that overrides the first creation on the object (in my case it was coupons).

Now you can use it like this:

```
c.type == :type_one
c.type = :type_two
```

Comment: You can add `.with_indifferent_access` to the `TYPE_MAP` to allow for string access

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [active_enum](https://github.com/adzap/active_enum).

I think it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use enum_column to add enum support to active record

https://github.com/mdsol/enum_column

Answer (score -3):

```
t.enum :file_type ,:limit => [:jpg, :png, :gif] ,:default => :gif
```

Comment: what plugin are you using for this? enum is not supported by default

Comment: script/plugin install svn://rubyforge.org/var/svn/enum-column/plugins/enum-column