# Datatype performance for static text

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-migrations

I am currently querying my database to check deals for lunch and dinner using a boolean datatype (Rails, ActiveRecord). I am going to be adding more meal options and do not want to store the static text in the database because I fear that it will affect performance.

What is the best way to store static strings in a DB that will be queried? I am thinking of saving it has an integer and setup a key (1=Lunch, 2=Dinner).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is an enum.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282710/how-do-i-describe-an-enumeration-column-in-a-rails-3-migration) has a bunch of suggestions about different gems you can use to get enum support in Rails 3.  In particular, if you're using MySQL, [this gem](https://github.com/electronick/enum_column) should do the trick.