# How to create a clickable hyperlink within a <pre> block in redmine textile?

Tags: redmine, textile

I want to paste a block of code or output into a redmine note and reference my source as a clickable URL below it.  In redmine's textile, the `<pre>` tag lets me post code.  But I would like the URL reference of that code to be clickable and indented as much as the content above it.

However, the `<pre>` tag disables the rendering of URLs into clikable hyperlinks.  Any way I can have a clickable hyperlink within a `<pre>` block in redmine's textile markup?

Comment: Is your question body the answer to your question title? If so, please answer your own question with the above, and update your question body to add some extra detail, separating out the two as an independent question and answer. It's perfectly fine (and even encouraged) to ask a [**self-answering question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in this regard :)

Comment: Thanks.  Done.  I'm sure I had checked the box "Answer your question". Guessed I missed the text area.  That kind of day.

Answer (score 2):

Prepend `<notextile></notextile>` to the first line of your `<pre>` block.

```
<pre>
<notextile></notextile>t.integer :status
-- http://stackoverflow.com/a/21185479/1611925
</pre>
```