# ROR radio buttons for dummies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have read the documentation on this, and still i have no idea how to do this.

I have a column in the table for :free that is a boolean

```
true  = free
false = paid
nil   = both
```

I'm trying to capture this same logic in my form and i'm doing an absolutely terrible job... so far everything comes up as free

index.html.erb:

```
 <div class="field">
    <label class="radio">
      <%= radio_button_tag(:free, "free", :checked => true) %>
      Free
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
      <%= radio_button_tag(:free, "paid") %>
      Paid
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
      <%= radio_button_tag(:free, "both") %>
      Both
    </label>
  </div>
```

resources_controller.rb (I know this isnt ideal because its checking the params every single time (even if they enter in wrong info) but i'm not sure how else to check if i can save it without saving it. Also... I dont even know if i did params right but i am not sure how to check it either. when i do `p params[:resources]` it doesnt print it how id like it to. is there a good way to do this kind of thing in rails?

```
def create
    @resource = Resource.new(params[:resource])

    if params[:resource][:free] = "free"
      @resource[:free] = true
    elsif params[:resource][:free] = "both"
      @resource[:free] = nil
    else
      @resource[:free] = false
    end

    if @resource.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render :action => :new
    end 
  end
```

resources_helper.rb

```
  def output_free
    if @resource.free = true
      "Free"
    elsif @resource.free = false
      "Paid"
    else
      "Both"
    end
  end
```

Comment: You'll need `==` for comparison. And `nil` isn't a `Boolean`.

Comment: well, i feel so retarded. i have been staring at this way too long. i knew that :| as for boolean cant i use it to check for 3 states?

Comment: That's fuzzy logic, `true/false/null`. Does exist in SQL, you could used that, but that's magic you don't want. Use an `Enum` and three states - way clearer.

Comment: can you point me to a resource for Enum? I dont ever remember reading about that, particualrly how I might write this in the db migration

Comment: Nope, you need custom SQL when using AR. Datamapper has an Enum data type. You could use a simple `varchar(50)` column as well :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's fuzzy logic, true/false/null. Does exist in SQL, you could used that, but that's magic you don't want. Use an Enum and three states - way clearer.

And use `==` to compare :-)

Comment: and one last Q, how would i check the params without checking each time (evein if theres errors)?

Comment: No idea, ask another question :-)

Comment: I'm using this method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1263608/794481 and I keep getting the error TypeError: no implicit conversion from nil to integer when i try to save x = Resource.new

Comment: I added :default => 0, i think that might have been the problem

Comment: no, once again i am a moron, i used :cost => 0 instead of :free. thanks for all your help! after 10 hours of rails im really making sloppy mistakes :S